# Is this a good way to add protocols to a class I'm hooking in?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, logos

I'm trying to write a test tweak for iOS 8.3 using Theos.

This tweak will show a UIAlertView with two choices when the user taps on an application's icon.

I want to distinguish between the buttons, and to do so I need to add the `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

Following [this](https://github.com/DHowett/theos-logos-examples/blob/master/logos.subclass/Tweak.xm) example written by DHowett, I've adapted his code to run under iOS 8.3.

The code compiles and loads fine but no action is triggered when I tap on any icon.

If I simply hook into `SBApplicationIcon` with the correct method, action is triggered but this way I'm not able to distinguish button press.

Is this still a good way to add protocols?

Comment: Add some code, how you implemented alert and other code.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the class you're hooking into to `id<ProtocolName>` when setting the delegate.

For instance, in your case it would be something like:

```
[alert setDelegate: (id<UIAlertViewDelegate>) self];
```